# Nvidia Docker for Ubuntu 21.04?

Tags: nvidia, docker, compatibility, 21.04, unsupported-packages

someone was able to install NVidia Docker on Ubuntu 21.04? It does not allow me to download it due to compatibility issues. apparently there is no support yet.

[Installation Guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/cloud-native/container-toolkit/install-guide.html)

any solution? Thank you so much

Answer (score 6):

It is not official, but you can change the `distribution` variable on the [instruction page](https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/cloud-native/container-toolkit/install-guide.html#setting-up-nvidia-container-toolkit) into `ubuntu20.04`, like this:

```bsh
distribution='ubuntu20.04' \
   && curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/gpgkey | sudo apt-key add - \
   && curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/$distribution/nvidia-docker.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-docker.list
```

The rest is the same:

```bsh
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y nvidia-docker2
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Then, you can check your installation:

```bsh
sudo docker run --rm --gpus all nvidia/cuda:11.0-base nvidia-smi
```

Should return something like this:

```bsh
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.51.06    Driver Version: 450.51.06    CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla T4            On   | 00000000:00:1E.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   34C    P8     9W /  70W |      0MiB / 15109MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

N.B.
I just need to use `nvidia-docker` to do some deep learning with tensorflow, and the solution I gave above has no problem for training and inferencing.

Comment: If you're comfortable with the usage of "-y", i.e., if you know what you're doing, it's fine. For instructions or answers here please avoid it.

Comment: I love you!  I love you!

Answer (score 0):

Add repos: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-docker.list

```
deb https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/ubuntu18.04/amd64 /
deb https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-container-runtime/ubuntu18.04/amd64 /
deb https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/ubuntu18.04/amd64 /
```

and

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y nvidia-docker2
```